# Generate the maximum combinations and get the lowest price

Tags: php

I need to generate the maximum combinations and get the lowest price based on the search of products performed by the user & the products that each customer has.

```
// List of products that the user is searching
$searching = 
[
    ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 50],
    ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50],
];

// List of customers that have the products the user is looking for
$customers = 
[
    [
        'name' => 'A', 
        'products' => 
        [
            ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 10],
            ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 100, 'unit_price' => 10],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'B', 
        'products' => 
        [
            ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 20, 'unit_price' => 5],
            ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 12],
        ]
    ],
];
```

- The parameter `quantity` in `$searching` variable, represents the amount of quantity needed
- The parameter `quantity` in `$customers` variable, represents the amount of quantity available

Taking in consideration the input provided, the output should have at least 3 combinations:

```
[
    0 => 
    [
        'net_total' => 1000,
        'combinations' => 
        [
            [
                'name' => 'A',  
                'products' => 
                [
                    ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 10],
                    ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 10],
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
    1 => 
    [
        'net_total' => 1000,
        'combinations' => 
        [
            [
                'name' => 'B', 
                'products' => 
                [
                    ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 20, 'unit_price' => 5],
                    ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 12],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'A', 
                'products' => 
                [
                    ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 30, 'unit_price' => 10],
                ]
            ],            
        ]
    ],    
    2 => 
    [
        'net_total' => 900,
        'combinations' => 
        [
            [
                'name' => 'B', 
                'products' => 
                [
                    ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 20, 'unit_price' => 5],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'A', 
                'products' => 
                [
                    ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 30, 'unit_price' => 10],
                    ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 10],
                ]
            ],            
        ]
    ],
]
```

And we can see that the lowest price combination would be the index 2 of 900$.

I'm currently able to show the first 2 index's (0 & 1), but haven't figure out how am I suppose to create the combination of the index 2, which leads to the lowest price.

**The full code** (test online https://onlinephp.io/c/98dcc)

```
$searching = 
[
    ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 50],
    ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50],
];

$customers = 
[
    [
        'name' => 'A', 
        'products' => 
        [
            ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 10],
            ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 100, 'unit_price' => 10],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'B', 
        'products' => 
        [
            ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 20, 'unit_price' => 5],
            ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 12],
        ]
    ],
];

$combinations = combinations($customers, $searching);

print_r($combinations);

// Generates all the combinations
function combinations($customers, $searching)
{
    $combinations = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($customers); $i++)
    {
        list($products, $netTotal) = findProducts($customers[$i]['products'], $searching);

        $combination = [];
        $combination['net_total'] = $netTotal;
        $combination['combinations'] = 
        [
            [
                'name' => $customers[$i]['name'],
                'products' => $products,
            ]
        ];
        
        for ($y = 0; $y != $i; $y++)
        {
            // Grabs the missing products from the combination / also checks the quantity needed
            $missingProducts = missingProducts($combination['combinations'], $customers[$y], $searching);

            // No missing products, the current customer have all the combinations needed
            if (!$missingProducts)
                break;

            list($products, $netTotal) = findProducts($missingProducts, $searching);

            $combination['net_total'] += $netTotal;
            $combination['combinations'][] = 
            [
                'name' => $customers[$y]['name'],
                'products' => $products,
            ];
        }

        $combinations[] = $combination;
    }

    return $combinations;
}

// Finds the products of a given customer 
function findProducts($customerProducts, $searching)
{
    $products = [];
    $netTotal = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($customerProducts); $i++)
    {
        $index = null;

        for ($y = 0; $y < count($searching); $y++)
        {
            // Customer has the product that is currently being searched
            if ($searching[$y]['id'] == $customerProducts[$i]['id'])
            {
                $index = $y;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is_null($index))
            continue;

        $qtyRequired = $searching[$index]['quantity'];
        $customerQty = $customerProducts[$i]['quantity'];
        $finalQty = $qtyRequired;

        // Checks if the customer available quantity is lower than the one being searched
        if ($customerQty < $qtyRequired)
            $finalQty = $customerQty;

        $products[] = 
        [
            'id' => $customerProducts[$i]['id'],
            'quantity' => $finalQty,
            'unit_price' => $customerProducts[$i]['unit_price'],
        ];

        $netTotal += $customerProducts[$i]['unit_price'] * $finalQty;
    }

    return [$products, $netTotal];
}

// Finds missing products in the current array combinations
function missingProducts($combinations, $customer, $searching)
{
    $necessaryProducts = [];
    $products = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($searching); $i++)
    {
        $indexY = null;
        $indexX = null;
        $quantityRequired = $searching[$i]['quantity'];

        // First check if combination already has the product
        for ($y = 0; $y < count($combinations); $y++)
        {
            for ($x = 0; $x < count($combinations[$y]['products']); $x++)
            {
                if ($combinations[$y]['products'][$x]['id'] == $searching[$i]['id'])
                {
                    $indexY = $y;
                    $indexX = $x;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Didn't find the product in the combination
        if (is_null($indexX))
            $necessaryProducts[] = $customer['products'];
        else
        {
            // Found the product in the combination & the current quantity in the combination is less than the required one
            if ($combinations[$indexY]['products'][$indexX]['quantity'] < $quantityRequired)
            {
                $temp = $searching[$i];
                $temp['quantity'] = $quantityRequired - $combinations[$indexY]['products'][$indexX]['quantity'];
                $necessaryProducts[] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // No necessary products to be added
    if (!$necessaryProducts)
        return;

    // There are products missing from the combination
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($necessaryProducts); $i++)
    {
        for ($y = 0; $y < count($customer['products']); $y++)
        {
            if ($necessaryProducts[$i]['id'] == $customer['products'][$y]['id'])
            {
                $customer['products'][$y]['quantity'] = $necessaryProducts[$i]['quantity'];
                $products[] = $customer['products'][$y];
            }
        }
    }

    return $products;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied a different logic, by separating each product in a individual group and makes it easier to create the combinations of groups.

```
[
    ['name' => 'A', 'product' => ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 10]],
    ['name' => 'A', 'product' => ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 100, 'unit_price' => 10]],
    ['name' => 'B', 'product' => ['id' => '001', 'quantity' => 20, 'unit_price' => 5]],
    ['name' => 'B', 'product' => ['id' => '002', 'quantity' => 50, 'unit_price' => 12]],
]
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/72c06

Some things must be applied after receiving the combinations, like deleting the duplicateds.